# How to Model Pummel (Sword Handle)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

[image]

I'm trying to make this pummel.  I'm not sure where to start.  If you look at the base of the blue circle where the red gem is there's a triangular shape. Ive tried extruding vertically but it isn't squared off enough

I think a lot has to do with the perspective of the picture but its the only one there is

I know the center and side orange gems are pretty sloppy but they're currently just place holders.

It looks like where the purple gems have some what of a square shape so I made a trapezoid type shape, poked the face a grabbed on the -z axis, then used the mirror modifier to make the one to the left and back side as well.

[image]

Comment: Think in small increments. Start by blocking out something very simple that is somewhat close to the shape you want and then make more incremental small improvements on it.

Comment: Please, start by adding a suitable title to your question. Make sure you describe your question or problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about. However, don't put every detail in your title... that's what the question body is for. This will help you to get more attention and probably the answer that you are looking for

Comment: Make a simple outline with quads and let subdivision smooth it for you

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the shape with some edges:

[image]

Then extrude, use the *Proportional Editing* to round it:

[image]

Pull or extrude what is supposed to be bumps:

[image]

Bevel the edges that are supposed to be sharp, etc:

[image]